# React CSS - How can I iterate and render multiple form field components if the flex direction is different for 2 of those fields?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have multiple input components and instead of hard writing them i want to iterate. All inputs have the same style (column and wide) except the input fields 'first name' and 'last name' - here I want them to be aligned in row and have different width.

```
<div style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
<div style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
<FormInput
       name="firstname"
       placeholder="First name"
       onChange={onChange}
       value={value}
       errors={errors}
       width="45%"
/>
<FormInput
       name="lastname"
       placeholder="Last name"
       onChange={onChange}
       value={value}
       errors={errors}
       width="45%"
/>
</div>
<FormInput
       name="email"
       placeholder="email"
       onChange={onChange}
       value={value}
       errors={errors}
       width="90%"
/>
...
</div>
```

```
Object.entries({firstname: 'Fist Name', lastname: 'Last Name', email: 'Email', password: 'Password', passwordConfirm: 'Confirm Password'}).map(item=> {
    return (
      <FormInput
       name={item[0]}
       placeholder={item[1]}
       onChange={onChange}
       value={value}
       errors={errors}
       width=??
      />
    )
})
```

How can I iterate through all input fields if 2 of them have different style (row)? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean you want to render first/last name fields differently from the others, then you need to show us the data structure you are working with. Chances are you will rely on destructuring (be it object or array), but without any [mcve] it's difficult to show you a proof-of-concept. How are the fields being stored?

Comment: i have edited it and included an example.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to destructure the array returned from `Object.entries` so that you treat the first two entries, which corresponds to first/last name fields, differently:

```
// NOTE: You might want to use `useMemo` if the object you're using may change
const [firstName, lastName, ...fields] = Object.entries({firstname: 'Fist Name', lastname: 'Last Name', email: 'Email', password: 'Password', passwordConfirm: 'Confirm Password'});

// Returning your template
return {
  <div style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
    <div style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <FormInput
            name={firstName[0]}
            placeholder={firstName[1]}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            errors={errors}
            width="45%"
      />
      <FormInput
            name={lastName[0]}
            placeholder={lastName[1]}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            errors={errors}
            width="45%"
      />
    </div>
    {fields.map(item=> (
      <FormInput
        name={item[0]}
        placeholder={item[1]}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        errors={errors}
        width="90%"
      />
    ))}
  </div>
}
```